# How to properly create mixins in Magento 2 JS?

Tags: magento2, requirejs

Hi I'd like to know what is the best way to create `mixins` in core `required-js`.

Instead of copying this files to working theme and make changes:

`vendor/magento/module-product-video/view/frontend/web/js/load-player.js`

```
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/**
 @version 0.0.1
 @requires jQuery & jQuery UI
 */
define(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    var videoRegister = {
        _register: {},

        /**
         * Checks, if api is already registered
         *
         * @param {String} api
         * @returns {bool}
         */
        isRegistered: function (api) {
            return this._register[api] !== undefined;
        },

        /**
         * Checks, if api is loaded
         *
         * @param {String} api
         * @returns {bool}
         */
        isLoaded: function (api) {
            return this._register[api] !== undefined && this._register[api] === true;
        },

        /**
         * Register new video api
         * @param {String} api
         * @param {bool} loaded
         */
        register: function (api, loaded) {
            loaded = loaded || false;
            this._register[api] = loaded;
        }
    };

    $.widget('mage.productVideoLoader', {

        /**
         * @private
         */
        _create: function () {
            switch (this.element.data('type')) {
                case 'youtube':
                    this.element.videoYoutube();
                    this._player = this.element.data('mageVideoYoutube');
                    break;

                case 'vimeo':
                    this.element.videoVimeo();
                    this._player = this.element.data('mageVideoVimeo');
                    break;
                default:
                    throw {
                        name: 'Video Error',
                        message: 'Unknown video type',

                        /**
                         * join name with message
                         */
                        toString: function () {
                            return this.name + ': ' + this.message;
                        }
                    };
            }
        },

        /**
         * Initializes variables
         * @private
         */
        _initialize: function () {
            this._params = this.element.data('params') || {};
            this._code = this.element.data('code');
            this._width = this.element.data('width');
            this._height = this.element.data('height');
            this._autoplay = !!this.element.data('autoplay');
            this._playing = this._autoplay || false;
            this._loop = this.element.data('loop');
            this._rel = this.element.data('related');

            this._responsive = this.element.data('responsive') !== false;

            if (this._responsive === true) {
                this.element.addClass('responsive');
            }

            this._calculateRatio();
        },

        /**
         * Abstract play command
         */
        play: function () {
            this._player.play();
        },

        /**
         * Abstract pause command
         */
        pause: function () {
            this._player.pause();
        },

        /**
         * Abstract stop command
         */
        stop: function () {
            this._player.stop();
        },

        /**
         * Abstract playing command
         */
        playing: function () {
            return this._player.playing();
        },

        /**
         * Destroyer
         */
        destroy: function () {
            this._player.destroy();
        },

        /**
         * Calculates ratio for responsive videos
         * @private
         */
        _calculateRatio: function () {
            if (!this._responsive) {
                return;
            }
            this.element.css('paddingBottom', this._height / this._width * 100 + '%');
        }
    });

    $.widget('mage.videoVimeo', $.mage.productVideoLoader, {

        /**
         * Initialize the Vimeo widget
         * @private
         */
        _create: function () {
            var timestamp,
                additionalParams = '',
                src;

            this._initialize();
            timestamp = new Date().getTime();
            this._autoplay = true;

            if (this._autoplay) {
                additionalParams += '&autoplay=1';
            }

            if (this._loop) {
                additionalParams += '&loop=1';
            }
            src = '//player.vimeo.com/video/' +
                this._code + '?api=1&player_id=vimeo' +
                this._code +
                timestamp +
                additionalParams;
            this.element.append(
                $('<iframe/>')
                    .attr('frameborder', 0)
                    .attr('id', 'vimeo' + this._code + timestamp)
                    .attr('width', this._width)
                    .attr('height', this._height)
                    .attr('src', src)
                    .attr('webkitallowfullscreen', '')
                    .attr('mozallowfullscreen', '')
                    .attr('allowfullscreen', '')
            );
            this._player = window.$f(this.element.children(':first')[0]);

            // Froogaloop throws error without a registered ready event
            this._player.addEvent('ready', function (id) {
                $('#' + id).closest('.fotorama__stage__frame').addClass('fotorama__product-video--loaded');
            });
        },

        /**
         * Play command for Vimeo
         */
        play: function () {
            this._player.api('play');
            this._playing = true;
        },

        /**
         * Pause command for Vimeo
         */
        pause: function () {
            this._player.api('pause');
            this._playing = false;
        },

        /**
         * Stop command for Vimeo
         */
        stop: function () {
            this._player.api('unload');
            this._playing = false;
        },

        /**
         * Playing command for Vimeo
         */
        playing: function () {
            return this._playing;
        }
    });
});
```

I want to update starting this line: ***$.widget('mage.videoVimeo', $.mage.productVideoLoader, {***

and on **_create** method.

And this file `vendor/magento/module-product-video/view/frontend/web/js/fotorama-add-video-events.js`

```
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

define([
    'jquery',
    'jquery/ui',
    'catalogGallery',
    'Magento_ProductVideo/js/load-player'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    /**
     * @private
     */
    var allowBase = true; //global var is needed because fotorama always fully reloads events in case of fullscreen

    /**
     * @private
     */
    function parseHref(href) {
        var a = document.createElement('a');

        a.href = href;

        return a;
    }

    /**
     * @private
     */
    function parseURL(href, forceVideo) {
        var id,
            type,
            ampersandPosition,
            vimeoRegex;

        /**
         * Get youtube ID
         * @param {String} srcid
         * @returns {{}}
         */
        function _getYoutubeId(srcid) {
            if (srcid) {
                ampersandPosition = srcid.indexOf('&');

                if (ampersandPosition === -1) {
                    return srcid;
                }

                srcid = srcid.substring(0, ampersandPosition);
            }

            return srcid;
        }

        if (typeof href !== 'string') {
            return href;
        }

        href = parseHref(href);

        if (href.host.match(/youtube\.com/) && href.search) {
            id = href.search.split('v=')[1];

            if (id) {
                id = _getYoutubeId(id);
                type = 'youtube';
            }
        } else if (href.host.match(/youtube\.com|youtu\.be/)) {
            id = href.pathname.replace(/^\/(embed\/|v\/)?/, '').replace(/\/.*/, '');
            type = 'youtube';
        } else if (href.host.match(/vimeo\.com/)) {
            type = 'vimeo';
            vimeoRegex = new RegExp(['https?:\\/\\/(?:www\\.|player\\.)?vimeo.com\\/(?:channels\\/(?:\\w+\\/)',
                '?|groups\\/([^\\/]*)\\/videos\\/|album\\/(\\d+)\\/video\\/|video\\/|)(\\d+)(?:$|\\/|\\?)'
            ].join(''));
            id = href.href.match(vimeoRegex)[3];
        }

        if ((!id || !type) && forceVideo) {
            id = href.href;
            type = 'custom';
        }

        return id ? {
            id: id, type: type, s: href.search.replace(/^\?/, '')
        } : false;
    }

    //create AddFotoramaVideoEvents widget
    $.widget('mage.AddFotoramaVideoEvents', {
        options: {
            videoData: '',
            videoSettings: '',
            optionsVideoData: ''
        },

        PV: 'product-video', // [CONST]
        VU: 'video-unplayed',
        PVLOADED: 'fotorama__product-video--loaded', // [CONST]
        VID: 'video', // [CONST]
        VI: 'vimeo', // [CONST]
        FTVC: 'fotorama__video-close',
        FTAR: 'fotorama__arr',
        TI: 'video-thumb-icon',
        isFullscreen: false,
        FTCF: '[data-gallery-role="fotorama__fullscreen-icon"]',
        Base: 0, //on check for video is base this setting become true if there is any video with base role
        MobileMaxWidth: 767,
        GP: 'gallery-placeholder', //gallery placeholder class is needed to find and erase <script> tag
        videoData: null,

        /**
         * Creates widget
         * @private
         */
        _create: function () {

            $(this.element).on('gallery:loaded',  $.proxy(function () {
                this.fotoramaItem = $(this.element).find('.fotorama-item');
                this._initialize();
            }, this));
        },

        /**
         *
         * @private
         */
        _initialize: function () {
            this._loadVideoData();

            if (this._checkForVideoExist()) {
                this._checkFullscreen();
                this._listenForFullscreen();
                this._checkForVimeo();
                this._isVideoBase();
                this._initFotoramaVideo();
                this._attachFotoramaEvents();
            }
        },

        /**
         *
         * @param {Object} options
         * @private
         */
        _setOptions: function (options) {

            if (options.videoData && options.videoData.length) {
                this.options.videoData = options.videoData;
            }
            this._initialize();
        },

        /**
         *
         * @private
         */
        _loadVideoData: function () {
            var $widget = this;

            if (!$widget.videoData) {
                $widget.videoData = $widget.options.VideoData;
            }

            $('#product-options-wrapper').find('[option-selected]').each(function () {
                var key = $(this).attr('attribute-code') + '_' + $(this).attr('option-selected');

                if ($widget.options.optionsVideoData && $widget.options.optionsVideoData[key]) {
                    $widget.options.VideoData = $widget.options.optionsVideoData[key];
                } else {
                    $widget.options.VideoData = $widget.videoData;
                }
            });

            if (!$('#product-options-wrapper').find('[option-selected]').length) {
                $widget.options.VideoData = $widget.videoData;
            }
        },

        /**
         *
         * @private
         */
        _checkFullscreen: function () {
            if (this.fotoramaItem.data('fotorama').fullScreen || false) {
                this.isFullscreen = true;
            }
        },

        /**
         *
         * @private
         */
        _listenForFullscreen: function () {
            var self = this;

            this.fotoramaItem.on('fotorama:fullscreenenter', $.proxy(function () {
                this.isFullscreen = true;
            }, this));
            this.fotoramaItem.on('fotorama:fullscreenexit', $.proxy(function () {
                this.isFullscreen = false;
                self._hideVideoArrows();
            }, this));
        },

        /**
         *
         * @param {Object} inputData
         * @param {bool} isJSON
         * @returns {{}}
         * @private
         */
        _createVideoData: function (inputData, isJSON) {
            var videoData = [],
                dataUrl,
                tmpVideoData,
                tmpInputData,
                i;

            if (isJSON) {
                inputData = $.parseJSON(inputData);
            }

            for (i = 0; i < inputData.length; i++) {
                tmpInputData = inputData[i];
                dataUrl = '';
                tmpVideoData = {
                    mediaType: '',
                    isBase: '',
                    id: '',
                    provider: ''
                };
                tmpVideoData.mediaType = this.VID;

                if (tmpInputData.mediaType !== 'external-video') {
                    tmpVideoData.mediaType = tmpInputData.mediaType;
                }

                tmpVideoData.isBase = tmpInputData.isBase;

                if (tmpInputData.videoUrl != null) {
                    dataUrl = tmpInputData.videoUrl;
                    dataUrl = parseURL(dataUrl);
                    tmpVideoData.id = dataUrl.id;
                    tmpVideoData.provider = dataUrl.type;
                    tmpVideoData.videoUrl = tmpInputData.videoUrl;
                }

                videoData.push(tmpVideoData);
            }

            return videoData;
        },

        /**
         *
         * @param {Object} fotorama
         * @param {bool} isBase
         * @private
         */
        _createCloseVideo: function (fotorama, isBase) {
            var closeVideo;

            this.fotoramaItem.find('.' + this.FTVC).remove();
            this.fotoramaItem.append('<div class="' + this.FTVC + '"></div>');
            this.fotoramaItem.css('position', 'relative');
            closeVideo = this.fotoramaItem.find('.' + this.FTVC);
            this._closeVideoSetEvents(closeVideo, fotorama);

            if (
                isBase &&
                this.options.videoData[fotorama.activeIndex].isBase &&
                $(window).width() > this.MobileMaxWidth) {
                this._showCloseVideo();
            }
        },

        /**
         *
         * @private
         */
        _hideCloseVideo: function () {
            this.fotoramaItem
                .find('.' + this.FTVC)
                .removeClass('fotorama-show-control');
        },

        /**
         *
         * @private
         */
        _showCloseVideo: function () {
            this.fotoramaItem
                .find('.' + this.FTVC)
                .addClass('fotorama-show-control');
        },

        /**
         *
         * @param {jQuery} $closeVideo
         * @param {jQuery} fotorama
         * @private
         */
        _closeVideoSetEvents: function ($closeVideo, fotorama) {
            $closeVideo.on('click', $.proxy(function () {
                this._unloadVideoPlayer(fotorama.activeFrame.$stageFrame.parent(), fotorama, true);
                this._hideCloseVideo();
            }, this));
        },

        /**
         *
         * @returns {Boolean}
         * @private
         */
        _checkForVideoExist: function () {
            var key, result, checker, videoSettings;

            if (!this.options.videoData) {
                return false;
            }

            if (!this.options.videoSettings) {
                return false;
            }
            result = this._createVideoData(this.options.videoData, false),
                checker = false;
            videoSettings = this.options.videoSettings[0];
            videoSettings.playIfBase = parseInt(videoSettings.playIfBase, 10);
            videoSettings.showRelated = parseInt(videoSettings.showRelated, 10);
            videoSettings.videoAutoRestart = parseInt(videoSettings.videoAutoRestart, 10);

            for (key in result) {
                if (result[key].mediaType === this.VID) {
                    checker = true;
                }
            }

            if (checker) {
                this.options.videoData = result;
            }

            return checker;
        },

        /**
         *
         * @private
         */
        _checkForVimeo: function () {
            var allVideoData = this.options.videoData,
                videoItem;

            for (videoItem in allVideoData) {
                if (allVideoData[videoItem].provider === this.VI) {
                    this._loadVimeoJSFramework();
                }
            }
        },

        /**
         *
         * @private
         */
        _isVideoBase: function () {
            var allVideoData = this.options.videoData,
                videoItem,
                allVideoDataKeys,
                key,
                i;

            allVideoDataKeys = Object.keys(allVideoData);

            for (i = 0; i < allVideoDataKeys.length; i++) {
                key = allVideoDataKeys[i];
                videoItem = allVideoData[key];

                if (
                    videoItem.mediaType === this.VID && videoItem.isBase &&
                    this.options.videoSettings[0].playIfBase && allowBase
                ) {
                    this.Base = true;
                    allowBase = false;
                }
            }

            if (!this.isFullscreen) {
                this._createCloseVideo(this.fotoramaItem.data('fotorama'), this.Base);
            }
        },

        /**
         *
         * @private
         */
        _loadVimeoJSFramework: function () {
            var element = document.createElement('script'),
                scriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];

            element.async = true;
            element.src = 'https://secure-a.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js';
            scriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(element, scriptTag);
        },

        /**
         *
         * @param {Event} e
         * @private
         */
        _initFotoramaVideo: function (e) {
            var fotorama = this.fotoramaItem.data('fotorama'),
                thumbsParent,
                thumbs,
                t;

            if (!fotorama.activeFrame.$navThumbFrame) {
                this.fotoramaItem.on('fotorama:showend', $.proxy(function (evt, fotoramaData) {
                    $(fotoramaData.activeFrame.$stageFrame).removeAttr('href');
                }, this));

                this._startPrepareForPlayer(e, fotorama);

                return null;
            }
            fotorama.data.map($.proxy(this._setItemType, this));

            thumbsParent = fotorama.activeFrame.$navThumbFrame.parent();
            thumbs = thumbsParent.find('.fotorama__nav__frame:visible');

            for (t = 0; t < thumbs.length; t++) {
                this._setThumbsIcon(thumbs.eq(t), t);
                this._checkForVideo(e, fotorama, t);
            }

            this.fotoramaItem.on('fotorama:showend', $.proxy(function (evt, fotoramaData) {
                $(fotoramaData.activeFrame.$stageFrame).removeAttr('href');
            }, this));
        },

        /**
         *
         * @param {Object} elem
         * @param {Number} i
         * @private
         */
        _setThumbsIcon: function (elem, i) {
            var fotorama = this.fotoramaItem.data('fotorama');

            if (fotorama.options.nav === 'dots' && elem.hasClass(this.TI)) {
                elem.removeClass(this.TI);
            }

            if (this.options.videoData[i].mediaType === this.VID &&
                fotorama.data[i].type ===  this.VID &&
                fotorama.options.nav === 'thumbs') {
                elem.addClass(this.TI);
            }
        },

        /**
         * Temporary solution with adding types for configurable product items
         *
         * @param {Object} item
         * @param {Number} i
         * @private
         */
        _setItemType: function (item, i) {
            !item.type && (item.type = this.options.videoData[i].mediaType);
        },

        /**
         * Attach
         *
         * @private
         */
        _attachFotoramaEvents: function () {
            this.fotoramaItem.on('fotorama:showend', $.proxy(function (e, fotorama) {
                this._startPrepareForPlayer(e, fotorama);
            }, this));
            this.fotoramaItem.on('fotorama:show', $.proxy(function (e, fotorama) {
                this._unloadVideoPlayer(fotorama.activeFrame.$stageFrame.parent(), fotorama, true);
            }, this));

            this.fotoramaItem.on('fotorama:fullscreenexit', $.proxy(function (e, fotorama) {
                fotorama.activeFrame.$stageFrame.find('.' + this.PV).remove();
                this._startPrepareForPlayer(e, fotorama);
            }, this));
        },

        /**
         * Start prepare for player
         *
         * @param {Event} e
         * @param {jQuery} fotorama
         * @private
         */
        _startPrepareForPlayer: function (e, fotorama) {
            this._unloadVideoPlayer(fotorama.activeFrame.$stageFrame.parent(), fotorama, false);
            this._checkForVideo(e, fotorama, fotorama.activeFrame.i);
            this._checkForVideo(e, fotorama, fotorama.activeFrame.i - 1);
            this._checkForVideo(e, fotorama, fotorama.activeFrame.i + 1);
        },

        /**
         * Check for video
         *
         * @param {Event} e
         * @param {jQuery} fotorama
         * @param {Number} number
         * @private
         */
        _checkForVideo: function (e, fotorama, number) {
            var videoData = this.options.videoData[number - 1],
                $image = fotorama.data[number - 1],
                videoEventIsSet = false;

            if ($image) {

                !$image.type && this._setItemType($image, number - 1);

                if ($image.type === 'image') {
                    $image.$navThumbFrame && $image.$navThumbFrame.removeClass(this.TI);
                    this._hideCloseVideo();

                    return;
                } else if ($image.$navThumbFrame && $image.type === 'video') {
                    !$image.$navThumbFrame.hasClass(this.TI) && $image.$navThumbFrame.addClass(this.TI);
                }

                $image = $image.$stageFrame;

                if ($image) {
                    videoEventIsSet = $image.hasClass(this.VU);
                }
            }

            if ($image && videoData && videoData.mediaType === this.VID && !videoEventIsSet) {
                $(fotorama.activeFrame.$stageFrame).removeAttr('href');
                this._prepareForVideoContainer($image, videoData, fotorama, number);
            }

            if (this.isFullscreen && this.fotoramaItem.data('fotorama').activeFrame.i === number) {
                this.fotoramaItem.data('fotorama').activeFrame.$stageFrame[0].click();
            }
        },

        /**
         * Prepare for video container
         *
         * @param {jQuery} $image
         * @param {Object} videoData
         * @param {Object} fotorama
         * @param {Number} number
         * @private
         */
        _prepareForVideoContainer: function ($image, videoData, fotorama, number) {
            $image.addClass('fotorama-video-container').addClass(this.VU);
            this._createVideoContainer(videoData, $image);
            this._setVideoEvent($image, this.PV, fotorama, number);
        },

        /**
         * Create video container
         *
         * @param {Object} videoData
         * @param {jQuery} $image
         * @private
         */
        _createVideoContainer: function (videoData, $image) {
            var videoSettings;

            if ($image.find('.' + this.PV).length !== 0) {
                return;
            }

            videoSettings = this.options.videoSettings[0];
            $image.append(
                '<div class="' +
                this.PV +
                '" data-related="' +
                videoSettings.showRelated +
                '" data-loop="' +
                videoSettings.videoAutoRestart +
                '" data-type="' +
                videoData.provider +
                '" data-code="' +
                videoData.id +
                '" data-width="100%" data-height="100%"></div>'
            );
        },

        /**
         *
         * @param {Object} $image
         * @param {Object} PV
         * @param {Object} fotorama
         * @param {Number} number
         * @private
         */
        _setVideoEvent: function ($image, PV, fotorama, number) {
            $image.find('.magnify-lens').remove();
            $image
                .off('click tap', $.proxy(this._clickHandler, this))
                .on('click tap', $.proxy(this._clickHandler, this));
            this._handleBaseVideo(fotorama, number); //check for video is it base and handle it if it's base
        },

        /**
         * Hides preview arrows above video player.
         * @private
         */
        _hideVideoArrows: function () {
            var arrows = $('.' + this.FTAR);

            arrows.removeClass('fotorama__arr--shown');
            arrows.removeClass('fotorama__arr--hidden');
        },

        /**
         *
         * @param {Event} event
         * @private
         */
        _clickHandler: function (event) {
            if ($(event.target).hasClass(this.VU) && $(event.target).find('iframe').length === 0) {

                $(event.target).removeClass(this.VU);
                $(event.target).find('.' + this.PV).productVideoLoader();

                $('.' + this.FTAR).addClass(this.isFullscreen ? 'fotorama__arr--shown' : 'fotorama__arr--hidden');
            }
        },

        /**
         * Handle base video
         * @param {Object} fotorama
         * @param {Number} srcNumber
         * @private
         */
        _handleBaseVideo: function (fotorama, srcNumber) {
            var waitForFroogaloop,
                videoData = this.options.videoData,
                activeIndex = fotorama.activeIndex,
                number = parseInt(srcNumber, 10),
                activeIndexIsBase = videoData[activeIndex];

            if (!this.Base) {
                return;
            }

            if (activeIndexIsBase && number === 1 && $(window).width() > this.MobileMaxWidth) {
                if (this.options.videoData[fotorama.activeIndex].provider === this.VI) {
                    waitForFroogaloop = setInterval($.proxy(function () {
                        if (window.Froogaloop) {
                            clearInterval(waitForFroogaloop);
                            fotorama.requestFullScreen();
                            this.fotoramaItem.data('fotorama').activeFrame.$stageFrame[0].click();
                            this.Base = false;
                        }
                    }, this), 50);
                } else { //if not a vimeo - play it immediately with a little lag in case for fotorama fullscreen
                    setTimeout($.proxy(function () {
                        fotorama.requestFullScreen();
                        this.fotoramaItem.data('fotorama').activeFrame.$stageFrame[0].click();
                        this.Base = false;
                    }, this), 50);
                }
            }
        },


    });

    return $.mage.AddFotoramaVideoEvents;
});
```

Starting on widget loader:  ***$.widget('mage.AddFotoramaVideoEvents', {***

and ***_loadVideoData*** method.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to apply mixin is as following maybe it helps you  :

**app\code\Vendor\Module\view\frontend\requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    'config': {
        'mixins': {
            'Magento_ProductVideo/load_player': {'Vendor_Module/js/view/custom-load-player': true}
        }
    }
}
```

**app\code\Vendor\Module\view\frontend\web\js\view\custom-load-player.js**

```
    define(
        [
            'jquery'
        ],
        function ($) {
            'use strict';
..............................................................
.........Here you override function you want .................
..............................................................
        }
    );
```

Comment: hi @shashank Already this but there are some errors , I have created new question regarding mixin.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/293957/magento-2-rewrite-widget-function-with-mixins-magento-2-1-18-not-working